# Capistrano Deploying Error with .rvmrc file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I have ruby-2.0.0-p0 in my local machine. When I was deploying my rails application, I got lot of error and I had fix it and it was running. But again, after 1 days, I try to running same application, I got this message

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is not compatible with other ruby managers,
you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to [.]ruby-version'
or ignore this warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/Desktop/PV-NEC/pv-nec/.rvmrc',
'.rvmrc' will continue to be the default project file in RVM 1 and RVM 2,
to ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs'.

ruby-2.0.0-p195 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p195'
```

I have put `rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p195@rails3` code in my .rvmrc file. Should I need to change it or do something else.

Comment: hey, I change .rmvrc file in my local machine rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0 but does not .rmvrc in server. I put same ruby-2.0.0-p195 in .rmvrc file in server

Answer (score 0):

first install ruby as displayed in error with command:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p195
```

and create the appropriate gemset with command

```
   rvm gemset create gemset_name
```

and then type in this to switch from .rvmrc to .ruby-version + .ruby-gemset

```
rvm rvmrc to .ruby-version
```